# AJAX content loader only works with half my links

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a site using an AJAX content loader to bring in one div from all my HTML pages. It works on the links in my `#menu` section, but not in my `#thumbs` section.

Even when I switch the links to opposite sections, they only work in the `#menu` and still not the `#thumbs`. I've spent hours looking at this and switching things around, but still can't figure it out!

I've tried using `#thumbs a`, `#thumbs`, `#t1 a, #t2 a, #t3 a, #t4 a, #t5 a, #t6 a`, etc etc and still nothing!!

You can see the full site so far here: http://www.sarahubbarddesign.com/BP%20SITE-SHD/index.html
Any help is appreciated!

```
<div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/borealis_photo_logo.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <div class="menuContact"><a href="contact_bp.html" id="mC">Contact</a></div>
            <div class="menuAbout"><a href="about_bp.html" id="mA">About</a></div>
            <div class="menuHome"><a href="index.html" id="mH">Home</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="mainImage">
        <img src="images/homeImage.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div id="thumbs">
        <div id="t1"><a href="portfolio1_bp.html" id="p2"><img id="i1" src="images/thumbs/portThumb_snort.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div id="t2"><a href="portfolio2_bp.html" id="p2"><img id="i2" src="images/thumbs/portThumb_horse.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div id="t3"><a href="portfolio3_bp.html" id="p3"><img id="i3" src="images/thumbs/portThumb_pets.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div id="t4"><a href="portfolio4_bp.html" id="p4"><img id="i4" src="images/thumbs/portThumb_ppl.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div id="t5"><a href="portfolio5_bp.html" id="p5"><img id="i5" src="images/thumbs/portThumb_places.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <div id="t6"><a href="portfolio6_bp.html" id="p6"><img id="i6" src="images/thumbs/portThumb_things.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
    </div><!--END THUMBS DIV-->

//NEW-- LOAD CONTENT IN MAINIMAGE DIV AND CHANGE URL       
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $("#menu a, #thumbs a").each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
            var toLoad = hash+'.html #mainImage';
            $('#mainImage').load(toLoad)
        }
    });
    $("#menu a, #thumbs a").click(function(){             
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #mainImage';
        $('#mainImage').fadeOut("fast",loadContent);
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#mainImage').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            //Slider();
            $('#mainImage').fadeIn("1000");
            //Slider();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think theclick event is not being triggered on the link tag as it looks to be hidden on mouse over. Just as a brute force answer try

```
$("#thumbs div").click(function(){             
        var toLoad = $(this).children('a').attr('href')+' #mainImage';
        $('#mainImage').fadeOut("fast",loadContent);
        window.location.hash = $(this).children('a').attr('href').substr(0,$(this).children('a').attr('href').length-5);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#mainImage').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            //Slider();
            $('#mainImage').fadeIn("1000");
            //Slider();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

And also remove '#thumbs a' from the previous selector. Could you also post the css which handles the mouse over on thumbs?

Comment: That works! The only problem is that it doesn't add the hash at the end of the URL for the thumbs, which should be `#portfolio1_bp`, `#portfolio2_bp` etc... Do I need to repeat the first portion of the code targeting `#thumbs div` again?

Comment: I think that should work now I was targeting the link tag for the hash not the actual href attribute.

Comment: OK- I had to change the kind of image slider I was using, and now I'm having the same problem again. The `#menu` part works, but the `#thumbs` don't. Note: I've changed how the `#thumbs` div is set up and the image slider. I tried targeting the links in `#thumbs` a couple different ways again, but still nothing. Does it have to do with the way the slider is working now? (blueberry slider)
You can see the site here- http://sarahubbarddesign.com/BP%20SITE-SHD/index.html
Any suggestions?